# IntelliJ - Highlight where exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea

I want to see in my code where an exception is thrown. When I click on the IOException it should also highlight the `testFileFunction()` call in which the exception could be thrown.

```
public void testFunction() throws IOException {
  // This function can throw an IOException
  testFileFunction();
}
```

I found out that `CTRL+SHIFT+F7` highlights the exception an the try/catch block, but not if it was thrown in a called method. Does IntelliJ support this feature?

// Edit:
[image]

The line with the red underline should also be highlighted, because that is the function which throws the IOException.